# I'm designing a signup page in codeigniter but my form validation is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my code:

controller/register.php

```
function register() {
   $this->load->view('pages/register');
}

function validation() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|is_unique[register1.email]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('pages/register');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'pass' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->register_m->registration($data);
}
```

models/register_m.php

```
 function registration($data) {
     foreach($data as $key => $value){
         $a = explode(',', $key)[0];
     }
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('register1');
     $this->db->where('email',email);
     $this->db->limit(1);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
         $this->db->insert('register1', $data);
             if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                 return true;
             }
     } else {
         return false;
     }
  }
```

Now the problem is I do not get how to validate my email. Either this email is already register before or not. Can you please also visit my code to tell me if I have made a mistake during coding.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter 2 or 3?

Comment: ok i will but can you please tell me about my mistkae in this code or tell me how to validate that email is register before or not?

Comment: @JeroenvanVeghel am using codeigniter 3

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you please tell me how to get the email i entered in the model  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `is_unique[register1.email]` will look for the occurance in your **register1** table for you. If it exists it will flag an error. **See Form Validation errors in the user guide.**

So in your model, you have a big mistake...

**NOTE: This is untested**

> ```
>  $this->db->where('email',email); // what is email? a constant??
> ```

```
function registration($data) {
    // Does the email address already exist    
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('register1');
    $this->db->where('email', $data['email']); // email is already in your data array
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        // No so we can save it
        $this->db->insert('register1', $data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    } else {
        // The email address already exists so leave
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And you don't really need to check the email address again in your model but it's not harmful to do so depending on what else may be calling this... I don't know.

Update: Something to consider... When you are passing in arrays you should really test that the indexes like 'email' actually exist. You should test that all your expected $data entries exist before using it in database updates and inserts etc... Although at Design time, if you make a mistake with your $data entries, it will show up so you can fix it...

Comment: thank you so much for your help and good explanation.this is working

Comment: Grand :) I did add a little note on the end, just something to think about!

Comment: yes i check my $data array before to confirm that my data is stored or not in this array thanks again for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

As this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433147/im-designing-a-signup-page-in-codeigniter-but-my-form-validation-is-not-working#comment77827440_45433147) code indentation would be a good idea.

For Validation in CodeIgniter very simple to implement.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|is_unique[register1.email]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
```

Codeigniter will allow you to put your validation code in config.
For that, you need to create `form_validation.php` in `config` folder.

the file looks like this.

```
$config = array(
        'your_login_validation' => array(
        array(
                'field' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Name',
                'rules' => 'required|trim'
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|is_unique[register1.email]',
                'errors' => array(
                        'required' => 'You must provide a %s.',                     
                ),
        ),
        array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required'
        )
    )
);

and 


function validation() {
    if ($this->form_validation->run('your_login_validation') == TRUE) {
        // this will directly check the validation and gives the error if fail.         

    } else {
        // To back to view. 
    }

}
```

I also notice that you are creating an array of your post variable taking each post data separately. So I will suggest you use 
`$data = $this->input->post();` it will give you all post data at once. 
So your controller will look like this:

```
function validation() {

    if ($this->form_validation->run('your_login_validation') == TRUE) {
        $this->load->view('pages/register');
    } else {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $result = $this->register_m->registration($data);

        if($result == TRUE){
            // If you are doing login then you can set a session here
        }

    }

}

// Your model code
function registration($data) {

//You don't need to check email exists or not again. Codeigniter validation `is_unique` will take care of it. 

    $this->db->insert('register1', $data);
    // You can use [ $this->db->last_query(); ] to chekc the last query execution for better understanding. 
    // Also you can get last inserted id by using  [ $last_inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id(); ]

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    } else {
        // The email address already exists so leave
        return FALSE;
    }


}
```

For validation, you can also visit the [CodeIgniter documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

Comment: thank you so much fro your help i have solved my problem but thanks for your time and for your kindness

Comment: I have updated the answer with some more suggestion to improve the code :)  @ranaaqibJaveed